# Getting the base name of a file with a macro

Tags: macros

I am using conditional compilation to test the speed of compiling a huge book. This is the way I do it within a `\begin{figure}` environment:

```
\ifforceprecompiled
  \includegraphics{timeline.tex.pdf}
\else
  \ifstandalonemode
    \includetikz{timeline.tex}
  \else
    \includetikz{timeline.tikz}
  \fi
\fi
```

The problem with this approach is that if the figure was created with the `timeline.tikz` file, then the compiled figure is `timeline.tikz.pdf` and not `timeline.tex.pdf`, so I can't use the `ifforceprecompiled` macro in that case. I would like to do instead:

```
\ifforceprecompiled
  \includegraphics{timeline.pdf}.  % <- change here
\else
  \ifstandalonemode
    \includetikz{timeline.tex}
  \else
    \includetikz{timeline.tikz}
  \fi
\fi
```

But for that I need to somehow get only the base name of the file (without the extension). I was wondering whether something like this could be done with a macro.

**UPDATE**

Following the advice of David Carlisle, this is what I have so far in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\myinclude}[1]{
\ifforceprecompiled
  \includegraphics{#1.pdf}
\else
  \ifstandalonemode
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}
    \input{#1.tex}
  \else
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}
    \input{#1.tikz}
  \fi
\fi
}
```

So I just pass the filename without the extension to the macro and everything is taken care of properly. However, one needs to be aware of not passing the extension, otherwise there's an error. I think still figuring out a way to obtain the base name of the file will make this macro more robust.

Comment: you could use `\filename@parse` (which is what `\includegraphics` uses internally) but I  would not have all those tests on every instance, just have `\myinclude{timeline}`  in the figure and define that to be `\includetikz{#1.tikz}` or `\includetikz{#1.tex}` or `\includegraphics{#1.pdf}` with a definition in  a single conditional block in the preamble

Answer (score 1):

In case the switches `\ifstandalonemode`/`\ifforceprecompiled` are independent from each other and in case of "forceprecompiled"

- standalone-mode always goes along with using `timeline.tex.pdf`
- non-standalone-mode always goes along with using `timeline.tikz.pdf`

, you can—[as suggested by David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666189/getting-the-base-name-of-a-file-with-a-macro/666243#comment1656450_666189)—probably try s.th. like this:

Preamble:

```
\ifstandalonemode
  \ifforceprecompiled
     \newcommand\myinclude[1]{\includegraphics{#1.tex.pdf}}% or #1.pdf
  \else
     \newcommand\myinclude[1]{\includetikz{#1.tex}}%
  \fi
\else
  \ifforceprecompiled
    \newcommand\myinclude[1]{\includegraphics{#1.tikz.pdf}}% or #1.pdf
  \else
    \newcommand\myinclude[1]{\includetikz{#1.tikz}}%
  \fi
\fi
...
```

document-environment:

```
...
\myinclude{timeline}%
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `\IfFileExists{<file>}{<true>}{<false>}` since there's only two options really.

In the mockup below I have two "pre-compiled" images in the project/source folder:

- `example-image-a.tex.pdf`
- `example-image-b.tikz.pdf`

These are copies of the similarly-named `example-image`s from [`mwe`](//ctan.org/pkg/mwe), just for the example.

With `\forceprecompiledtrue`, you'll see that either of the precompiled output (`.tex.pdf` and `.tikz.pdf`) is included as needed, depending on the file that is availble for inclusion. You may have to use a similar conditional within the other pathway(s).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\includefigure}{ O{} m }{%
  \ifforceprecompiled
    \IfFileExists{#2.tex.pdf}
      {\includegraphics[#1]{#2.tex.pdf}}
      {\includegraphics[#1]{#2.tikz.pdf}}%
  \else
    \ifstandalonemode
      \includetikz{#2.tex}% May need to condition here as well
    \else
      \includetikz{#2.tikz}% May need to condition here as well
    \fi
  \fi
}

\newif\ifforceprecompiled
\newif\ifstandalonemode

\forceprecompiledtrue

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includefigure[height=3em]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Example image~A}

  \bigskip
  
  \includefigure[height=3em]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Example image~B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```